# Convert minutes into hours in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to convert 300 minutes into 5 hours.

Input is **300** Output should be **05:00**

Comment: Wh ou ask the same question twice?

Comment: SELECT TO_CHAR('300 minutes'::interval, 'HH24:MI')

Comment: @Jens it's a PostgreSQL database this time, not an Sybase database

Comment: If you know how it works in sybase, have you tried anything to convert it to postgresql?

Comment: Yes I tried, but it didn't work the same.

Comment: Source column data type? Result data type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert it to an interval, and format that usin `to_char()`

```
to_char(make_interval(mins => 300), 'HH24:MI')
```

The `FM` prefix avoids padding the result with blanks